# Quick Javascript inheritance: Understanding __proto__

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

Given the following constructor,

```
Dog = function(name, age, ...){
    Animal.call(this, name, age, ...);
    // And some other stuff that dogs do
}
```

I use the following line of code to copy my methods and properties across from the `Animal` class,

```
Dog.prototype = new Animal();
```

Could you enlighten me as to how that differs from

```
Dog.prototype.__proto__ = Animal.prototype;
```

since they seem to have the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__proto__` is a non-standard extension to JavaScript (common in various interpreters, but non-standard) that gives you direct access to the prototype behind an object. The `prototype` property of function objects is the object that *will be* assigned as the prototype behind an object created by calling the function via `new`. So when you assign to `prototype.__proto__`, you're assigning to the prototype behind the object that will be set as the prototype on new objects created by the function.

Since the way the prototype chain works is that properties on a prototype show up as inherited properties on an object (and this continues in a chain), if you assign to `Dog.prototype.__proto__`, the objects created by `Dog` will have access to those properties indirectly through the chain:

```
+-----------------+      +----------------+      +-------------------------+
| instance of Dog |----->| Dog.prototype  |----->| Dog.prototype.__proto__ |
|                 |      |                |      | `foo` property          |
|                 |      |                |      | `bar` property          |
+-----------------+      +----------------+      +-------------------------+
```

When you assign directly to `Dog.prototype`, the instances have a more direct reference:

```
+-----------------+      +----------------+
| instance of Dog |----->| Dog.prototype  |
|                 |      | `foo` property |
|                 |      | `bar` property |
+-----------------+      +----------------+
```

(Note that the above is *slightly* misleading by referring to `Dog.prototype` like that. Instances of `Dog` will get a direct reference to the object on `Dog.prototype` as of when `new Dog` is called; if you assign a completely different object to `Dog.prototype` later, instances that already exist will have the old prototype and new instances will get the new one. But that's a side-point.)

Comment: Also worth pointing out that *Dog.prototype.__proto__* is likely either *Object.prototype* or *Function.prototype* (depending on the object assigned as *Dog.prototype*) unless a more extensive chain has been established. So properties added to it may be inherited by all functions or objects (which includes all functions since they inherit from *Object.prototype* too).

Comment: @RobG: Yes, good point. The OP was *replacing* `__proto__` rather than assigning to properties on it, but still, if they did add properties to it instead, it would likely be...ugly. :-)

Answer (score 5):

`__proto__` lets you access the internal `[[Prototype]]` attribute of an object. It can be used to get or set the prototype of an already ***existing* object**.

`protoype` is a property of a function to set the prototype of **objects that *will* be created** by that function.

Afaik, only Firefox lets you use `__proto__`. [**It is not standard and deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto).

---

Worth reading:

- [*MDC - Inheritance and the constructor's prototype*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype)
- [*MDC - Inheritance revisited*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited)

Comment: Great, thanks, added those two to my stack of open tabs for reading. :)