# Assigning an object prototype after creation

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototype-programming

All examples and questions I've came upon searching on the web about prototypal inheritance shows the assigning of prototypes to **constructor functions** and before it's called, much like the following code:

```
Object.beget = function (o) {
    var F = function () {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};
```

My question is, is there a way to change an **object** (**not a constructor function**) prototype after it has been instatiated in such a way that I can access the new prototype methods without calling it directly, or in other words, in such a way where the **object** inherits its **new prototype methods**?

*EDIT:*

I guess the focus of the question might not be clear, I am not interested in enhancing an object's prototype, what I really want is a way to assign a new prototype, without altering other objects which had the same prototype as the first.

Comment: instead of trying to hijack a prototype for a single instance, just create a new object instance.

Comment: @zzzzBov That would work, but I don't want to pass all values the previous object had to the new one.

Comment: That's why it's common to see an `extend` method. [jQuery has one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), and [so does underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the prototype of a JavaScript object that has already been instantiated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7015693/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change an object's prototype after it has been instatiated?

Yes, there is: [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) (ES6 only), the counterpart of [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) - which access an object's real prototype, not just the `.prototype` property. There is also the [`.__proto__` getter/setter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) (deprecated) that does the same (see [Quick Javascript inheritance: Understanding __proto__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6225562/1048572)).

However, please notice that it is usually a terrible idea to do that. Not only because there may be [engines that don't support these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14688774/1048572), but it defeats all the fancy optimisations an engine uses of instances: [Why is mutating the [[prototype]] of an object bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks alot for your answer and references @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

You can assign new properties to your original object, o, and the new object instance will automatically have access to those properties:

```
Object.beget = function (o) {
    var F = function () {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};

var o = {
    a: 1
};

var instance = Object.beget(o);

instance.a === o.a; // true

o.b = function () {};

instance.b === o.b; // true
```

Comment: Actually, my doubt is the other way around, I dont want to enhance an previous prototype, I would like to change an **object** prototype entirely without changing the prototype of other objects which had the same prototype.

Answer (score 0):

If the prototype associated with the object changes after creation of object (which means all the properties that have come from previous prototype chain should be removed and new properties are added), isn't it equal to creating a instance of new object with this new prototype? In which case, why not create a new object and use it instead?

Please let me know if I am missing any use case.

Comment: As I mentioned in another commentary, the solution of creating a new Object would work, but it's not the same as 'hijacking' the object's prototype, as all values of the previous object attributes would have to be transfered to the new one, besides the overhead of creating a new instance.